# Extract rows based on the range in another file

Tags: text-processing, awk

`price.txt` file has two columns:(name and value)

```
Mary 134
Lucy 56
Jack 88
Marissa 37
Emily 85
Antony 99
```

`range.txt` file also has two columns:(fruit and value)

```
apple 57
banana 62
orange 88
blueberry 98
```

The second column of `range.txt` is ***ordered (from minimum to maximum)***

My aim is to extract rows of `price.txt` of which the values are within the range of values (57 - 98) in `range.txt` file.

The expected result is as follows:

```
Jack 88
Emily 85
```

I try to solve this by using the following code, but I don't know how to select the first line and the last line of the specific column. The unclear parts of the code are between asterisks (`**...**`):

```
awk 'FNR == NR {value=$2; **low=??; high=??**; next} 
     {if ($2>=**low** && $2<=**high** ) print $0}' range.txt price.txt
```

Comment: Thank you @don_crissti  But I don't know how to get the `low` value. It seems that the $2 of the first file is the maximum value (98).

Comment: `awk 'FNR == NR {high=$2; if(NR==1) low=high; next} 
     {if ($2>=low && $2<=high ) print $0}' range.txt price.txt`

Comment: It works!  Big Big Thanks! @don_crissti  O(∩_∩)O Nice ending of today's work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR == NR {high=$2; if(NR==1) low=high; next} 
     {if ($2>=low && $2<=high ) print $0}' range.txt price.txt
```

When `FNR == NR`, it will read the `range.txt` file, here we assign the second column of `range.txt` file to `high`, and use `if(NR==1) low=high` to assign the first value of `high` to `low`, then we can use these values in the next `if` sentence. And the `print $0` will print out the rows meeting the condition.